# Is it possible to stop profiling without stopping the target service? VS2010

Tags: service, profiler

I'm using the VS 2010 GUI profiler to profile a service on my machine. I have to attach to a running service. When I stop the profiling session it kills the service. I don't think that it did that in VS2008. In any case I can't find any option that will allow the service to keep running.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

If you attach to the running service you should also be able to detach from the service.

Instead of choosing 'stop profiling', open the 'Attach Profiler to Process' dialog and select the service process and choose 'Detach'.